# Is there a design pattern or recognised technique for comparing objects

Tags: design-patterns

I have a video class, which can have many tags associated with it. A while ago, I read an article about a design-pattern(or perhaps it was just a standard way of doing this) which detailed the most efficient and accurate way of working out how similar two video classes are by looking at how many of the same tag records they have associated with them.

Perhaps this isn't such a good example, as I could just order/group the tag count for each video, but i certainly recall reading about such a techniques.
Sorry for the vagueness of the question.

Comment: Sounds more like an algorithm than a design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you mean, but i immediately thought of [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). In short this is the number of edits needed to go from one to the other. (So the lower the levenshtein distance, the more the objects are similar)